# J2ME NetBeans6.9 GameBuilder

Tags: netbeans, java-me, netbeans-6.9

First you open the GameBuilder, and create the sprites, Tiled Layers and a scene,
now how do i make it appear in the display on the emulator?
i tried creating a VisualMIDlet
and inserting this code
 public void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException  {

```
  try {
  display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  GameDesign gameCanvas = new GameDesign();
  gameCanvas.start();
  Display.setCurrent(gameCanvas);

}
catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println(ex);
}
}
```

but in the line
Display.setCurrent(gameCanvas);
the program generates the error

```
  Display.setCurrent(gameCanvas);
method Display.setCurrent(Displayable) is not applicable
  (actual argument GameDesign cannot be converted to Displayable by method invocation conversion)
method Display.setCurrent(Alert,Displayable) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

what can i do? 
maybe its an error in the class?
thanks